# Button onClick got 2 error message when I use Async

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What is wrong with my code? it shows with the error of:

**1. cant resolve method onCreate 'onCreate.android.os.Bundle'

 2. Method does not override method from its superclass on @Override**

this is the section that got error message

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            BUTTON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            BUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    DemoAsync UploadFile = new DemoAsync();
                    UploadFile.execute();
                }
            });

        }
```

This is the whole code on MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.threadexample;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.TextView;


        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            public static final String DEMO_ASYNC = "DemoAsync";
            private TextView B_PRESSED;
            Button BUTTON;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                B_PRESSED = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
                DemoAsync demoAsync = new DemoAsync();
                demoAsync.execute("Button Pressed");

            }

            private class DemoAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                }

                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    Log.d(DEMO_ASYNC, "status : doInBackground");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(DEMO_ASYNC, e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return params[0];
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    B_PRESSED.setText(s);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                    BUTTON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

                    BUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            DemoAsync UploadFile = new DemoAsync();
                            UploadFile.execute();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }
```

Please give details what section that I should change, I'm new with this. Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, hope this will work

```
package com.example.threadexample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.marsad.wallpaperapp.R;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String DEMO_ASYNC = "DemoAsync";
    private TextView B_PRESSED;
    Button BUTTON;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        B_PRESSED = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        DemoAsync demoAsync = new DemoAsync();
        demoAsync.execute("Button Pressed");

        BUTTON = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        BUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DemoAsync UploadFile = new DemoAsync();
                UploadFile.execute();
            }
        });

    }

    private class DemoAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Log.d(DEMO_ASYNC, "status : doInBackground");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(DEMO_ASYNC, e.getMessage());
            }
            return params[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            B_PRESSED.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works thank you, could you please provide some reasoning on why my code doesnt work ? and it still give back error message eventhought I manage to execute the program on virtual android phone 4.0.3

Comment: it suddenly stop about a few seconds after i click the button and the "Button Pressed" string shows up

Comment: this is because onCreate method is already defined but you create another that is why this error occures

Comment: Sorry I just realised that the programs worked but it didnt exactly worked as I wanted to. I mean eventhought I didnt press the button, the text will changed by itself after 20 seconds, what should I do?

Comment: yeah thanks but it still forced closed on its own, anyone knows why?

Comment: does your app crash

Comment: yes it is, I tried on another device and its still crashed

Comment: I will put it on my answer, please check

Comment: You are running the AsyncTask like new MyAsyncTask().execute(); which means you are not passing any argument to it.

But in doInBackground method you are trying to get a value at String newstr=args[0];but args array has length 0.

Comment: take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846544/java-lang-runtimeexception-an-error-occured-while-executing-doinbackground

Comment: another answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946228/java-lang-runtimeexception-an-error-occured-while-executing-doinbackground/8946285

Comment: and ```Thread.sleep(20000);``` used to  suspend current thread

Answer (score 0):

```
03-30 18:59:49.026 3179-3196/com.example.threadexample W/dalvikvm: threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9800f180)
03-30 18:59:49.026 3179-3196/com.example.threadexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at com.example.threadexample.MainActivity$DemoAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:52)
        at com.example.threadexample.MainActivity$DemoAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
03-30 18:59:49.846 3179-3179/com.example.threadexample D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-30 18:59:50.386 3179-3179/com.example.threadexample D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x91275f8: ver 2 0
03-30 18:59:50.386 3179-3179/com.example.threadexample D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 1)
```

Comment: delete this answer